# JavaScript assign certain variables to a specific scope

Tags: javascript

Say I have the function

```
function hi() {
    console.log(bye); //error, since not defined
}
```

How would I be able to do something like this

```
function hi() {
    console.log(bye); //42
}

hi.addVariable("bye", 42);

hi(); //42

console.log(bye) //error, not defined in global scope, only above local one
```

I know to set a global variable you can do window.varname="hithere", but how can you do the same to the scope of a function, to be able to set variables to it's scope?

EDIT
possible compromise: is there a way to check what names / order the variables are entered, when calling the function? For example

```
function hi(bye, why, cry, lie) {
    console.log(bye, why)
}

if(hi.arguments.indexOf("why") == 1)//do something, aka pass certain value to the "why" argument
```

Comment: No, this is not possible. Pass it as argument into the function.

Comment: Why would you want to do this instead of passing the variable in some fashion?

Comment: if only you have `this.bye` rather `bye` inside the function, you can use `apply, call or bind`

Comment: @VLAZ because I have a lot of variables for the user to have to manually enter in, or enter in an object and manually access it's properties each time the value is needed, it would be a lot easier to just be able to magically declare all of the variables need in an outside function so the user doesn't even need to worry about it

Comment: @AZ_ I'm trying to use this mainly in arrow functions also so "this" wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the variable to your function

```
 var bye = 42; 

 function hi(bye) {
   console.log(bye); //42
 }

 hi(bye); //42

 console.log(bye) //42
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `bind` or `call` methods to create or call your function that will have passed object accessible on `this` inside the function. So you can use `this` inside the function to access those values.

```js
function hi() {
  const {bye} = this;
  console.log(bye); 
}

hi.call({bye: 42})

const withBye = hi.bind({bye: 42});
withBye();

console.log(typeof bye)
```

Comment: To be clear: yes, this is *a* way to do "it", but it's not really clear what "it" is that OP is trying to do here, so I wouldn't recommend this blindly as general solution when function arguments would do just as well or better.

Comment: `const bye = 42` will make the scope of the variable outside the function OP doesnt want that, `hi.call({bye:42})`?

Comment: @deceze I agree but this solution might provide some value to OP in case that for some reason he can't use arguments.

Comment: Thaaaaat would be an extremely weird situation. 

Comment: Well lets say he has a function that already has a lot of parameters, and he has already used that function in number of different places in his application and now he doesn't want to add new parameter but also doesn't want to polute the global scope also. Or something like that, idk :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without writing anything extra in the function itself, or possibly by just making a single function call like "constify(this)", which that would automatically set "function constify(func){const {bye} = func}"? Obviously done like shown won't declare anything in the other function , but how can I do this? In trying to make a JavaScript library which uses can use predefined variables and methods without the use of 1) global variables AND 2) object properties

Comment: @bluejayke I suggest you focus on what you're actually trying to achieve. What you seem to have right now is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @nenad will this also work for multiple properties?

Comment: @VLAZ theoretically, I just couldn't imagine any way to get the same results. If it's possible to simply "globalize" an objects properties only within that scope, that would also be great, there's got to be some kind of way to do this? This would also come in handy if the user can pass some kind of string like "import x from y as g", then the local variable g would be set to x.y... get what I'm trying to say?

Comment: Yes any property you pass with that object will be accessible on `this` inside the function.As VLAZ said it this sounds like XY problem. If you have a function with lots of parameters, maybe consider modifying your function to receive a object and then also look into default parameter values and object parameter destructuring. Also consider some design patterns like Strategy or State.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by `object function` , `global bye` will be undefined and `local bye` will be 42 after addVariable function called

```js
var hi = {
    bye : null,
    addVariable: function(varName, value)  {
       hi[varName] = value;
    }
}

console.log('Before addVariable called, bye is '+ hi.bye);

hi.addVariable("bye", 42);

console.log('After addVariable called , bye is '+ hi.bye);

console.log('Global bye is ' +bye)
```

Comment: I wouldn't say this really solves OP's problem. Mainly because I don't even know what OP's problem is. But this `hi` is very suprefluous - the `addVariable` can only really be used to change `bye` and even then you can just do it without the extra method by directly doing `hi["bye"] = 42`. This also doesn't really work with any other methods unless they already know what property of the object they should use. Which makes the `addVariable` doubly useless. All in all, it's a very roundabout way of just using objects and potentially also using something like `call`, `apply`, or `bind`.

Comment: @VLAZ yo to clarify I'm trying to make a JavaScript library where the user can simply use pre defined variables or methods, within certain functions only, without using global variables and without having to access the object properties, like obj.prop, that's not what I want

Answer (score 0):

I think this is closes to what you are asking. Using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to pass the variable into the function and return another function.

```js
function hi(bye) {
    console.log(bye);
}

hi = hi.bind({}, 42);

hi(); //42
```

EDIT: Your question is confusing and has been edited. Maybe you mean something like this:

```js
function hi() {
    console.log(hi.bye, hi.who);
}

hi.bye = 41;
hi.who = 42;

hi(); //41 42
```

Comment: @AZ_ indeed, the whole `bind` is completely useless here. It will wipe out the current function and replace it with a new one but the behaviour would be the same. Except the context cannot be changed.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, just wanted to point out that the question wouldn't even exist if the function was accepting a variable.

Comment: But how would this work for multiple variables, without having to define them individually as arguments in the function definition?